# Section formula

Tags: geometry

So I know from before that section formula ( ratio in which point divides line segment ) is $$( x , y ) = \left({ m x_2 + n x_1 \over m + n} ,  { m y_2 + n y_1 \over m + n}\right)$$

When $P$ divides $AB$ in the ratio $m: n$

[image]

Also the ratio will we $$x_1 -x : x - x_1$$
$$y_1 -y : y - y_1$$
Which is correct when we use similarity of triangle.

So what will happen when line is vertical? *(Area of triangle as 0)*
How can we get ratio only through x - coordinate?

Will ratio will become $0:0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio will surely not become $0:0$ as it would be undefined.

There is an acception with that formula for analogue of section formula.

**$x$-coordinate, not when the line is vertical; $y$-coordinate, not when the line is horizontal**

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the original slightly so that its image is no longer vertical.

Apply the section formula to the image.

Rotate the image back to its original position.

[image]

The figure clearly shows the said ratio still maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate B with as center A, radius AB. The circle so obtained has all radii divided in ratio $ m/n$ for all positions.